# Is Hankelability NP-hard?

Tags: computational-complexity

This question was previously [asked on cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31174/is-hankelability-np-hard) but with no answers or substantive comments.

I am trying to write code to detect if a matrix is a permutation of a Hankel matrix.  Here is the spec.

**Input:** An n by n matrix M whose entries are 1 or 0.

**Output:** Yes if there is a permutation of the rows and columns of M so that M is a [Hankel matrix](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) and No otherwise. A Hankel matrix has constant skew-diagonals (positive sloping diagonals).

When I say a permutation, I mean we can apply exactly one permutation to the order of the rows and a possibly different one to the order of the columns.

A very nice $O(n^2)$ time algorithm [is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704900/determine-if-some-row-permutation-of-a-matrix-is-toeplitz) for this problem if we only allow permutation of the order of rows.

Peter de Rivaz pointed out this [paper](http://www.mat.ucsb.edu/~g.legrady/academic/courses/15w259/d/re_orderableMatrix.pdf) as a possible route to proving NP-hardness but I haven't managed to get that to work.

> Is detecting Hankelability NP-hard?

Comment: Does Hankem matrices correspond to distance matrices for some nice family of graphs? If so, you are looking at a graph isomorphism problem, that is, to detect if a weighted graph is isomorphic to some graph in the "Hankel family"...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson It's an excellent question but the answer is, I don't know. That is I don't know what family of graphs this would correspond to.

Comment: If you allow both rows and columns to be permuted, then Hankelability would be the same as Toeplitzability, yes? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix)

Comment: @YoavKallus Yes that is right.

Comment: If I had a polynomial algorithm to decide Hankelability, it seems like I could use it to decide if a graph was cyclic or not, which would amount to determining whether its automorphism group had an element of order n. Since determining whether a graph has any nontrivial automorphism is just as hard as deciding if two graphs are isomorphic, it seems that your problem should also be at least this hard.

Comment: I realize what I wrote above is slightly wrong, but I think it works if you replace "cyclic graph" (by which I actually meant circulant) with "bipartite graph on 2n vertices with automorphism of order n that preserves the parts"